# HTML5 - Firefox

Tags: html5

I just can't get HTML 5 working with Ubuntu. I've followed another guide stating to install the package below, but this was unsuccessful in making my video work. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, with Firefox version 44.0.2.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

In my about:config page, the following is also set to enable

```
media.mediasource.enabled;true
```

When I do a HTML5 test on YouTube, I get the following results:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/49a4q2h31/]

I can't link you the video I am trying to watch as it's a paid-for training service (from ine.com). I can watch the video fine on a Windows PC, but I don't use Windows at home, so I need a solution.

EDIT:I have now tested with Google Chrome and it works, so the problem appears to be with Firefox. FYI I have disabled all extensions.

Comment: firefox supports html5 and I do not see any errors on the page you linked. As the video is a fee for service I suggest you contact them ;)

Comment: Are you sure it is HTML5? How does another browser, say Chrome, handle it?

Comment: Just installed chrome and it works. I will update my post to reflect this finding. It is clearly something with Firefox being a problem, but I don't understand what.

Comment: Is there any way I can get some log message output from when I click on the link? I would like to see the error in detail.